# Small home project

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code kinda looks like this:

```
import random

Employees = ["John", "tod", "mike", "Jim", "Kim", "liz", 
"lizzy", "jane", "nikki", "niko"]

Monday = []
Tuesday = []
Wednesday = []
Thursday =[]
Friday = []
Saturday = []
Sunday  = []
Off = []

Shift _one = random.choice(employees)
While Monday in range (3):
    Monday.append(shift_one)
Print(shift_one)
```

That's my code
I'm pretty sure there is a better way to write this.
I need to get this code to select 3 people for 3 shifts and the remainder to be added to off.
If /else statements I think will be needed. I can't seem to get the loop correct to select 3 people per day (or 3 people at all).

Comment: Is there a question here? It would make it easier for people trying to help you if you could provide some sample inputs and what you expect the output to look like. You indicate " I'm pretty sure there is better way to write this" which implies it is currently working (although I am unconvinced that this is the case). So what are you looking for in terms of improving it? Is the code too long? Does it take to long to execute? Assuming that it doesn't work, which bits do you need help with? What are the rules for picking people for a shift (or not picking people for a shift)?

Comment: Please refer to
[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are so right. I was just trying to get the basic skeleton of the code to function. The idea behind the code is would randomly choose a set amount of workers per shift. The plan is to introduce time into the code at some point within the future. It "works" there aren't any errors and it's output is one name. I'm just trying to get it to out put three random names per day, none of the names can be repeated more than 5x per week

Comment: This is not even valid Python syntax. It cannot possibly work or give you output.

Comment: @Clarke- Is this correct?  Workweek = 7 days, Employees per day = 3,  Max number of work days per employees = 5.   If so, please update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are roughly on the right track. One key thing you should look into is the difference between a `while` and a `for` loop as well as their general syntax. Also the placement of some of your lines was off. It takes practice, but eventually creation of loops become second nature. I wrote an example below for you to look at (note, the idx variable in the `for` loop is a placeholder variable):

```
for idx in range( 3 ):
    random_employee = random.choice( employees )
    Monday.append( random_employee )

print( Monday )

shift_one = Monday[ 0 ]
shift_two = Monday[ 1 ]
shift_three = Monday[ 2 ]

print( shift_one )
print( shift_two )
print( shift_three )
```

Comment: Wow just , wow. Reading your code -- I have so much to learn . I appreciate everyone's input on the project .